# Change entity reference field widget based on condition?

Tags: users, hooks

I am using Drupal 8. In user registration form, I use an entity reference field to a profile. I wanted to display inline entity reference form widget or entity select widget based on role.

For this, I tried to use `hook__field_widget_form_alter()`, but it didn't work.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For D7, you use [hook_field_widget_properties_ENTITY_TYPE_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_properties_ENTITY_TYPE_alter/7.x) but the problem is that in D8 this hook no longer exists.

Took a while to figure out an answer for D8, but here it is.

Since D8 allows you to create Form Display Modes:

#### 1) Add a form mode

[image]

#### 2) Select the entity type, User in this case

[image]

#### 3) Add name to it

[image]

#### 4) In Manage Form Display, click on Custom Display Settings and checkmark it

[image]

#### 5) Click on the alternate view mode and change widget

[image]

Then in custom module you change the view mode if it has a certain role

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_form_display_alter()
 */
function mymodule_entity_form_display_alter(\Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityFormDisplayInterface &$form_display, array $context) {
  if ($context['entity_type'] == 'user' && $context['bundle'] == 'user') {
    $current_user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
    if ($current_user->hasRole('administrator')) {
      // change the display mode
      $id = $context['entity_type'] . '.' . $context['bundle'] . '.alternate';
      $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getStorage('entity_form_display');
      $alt_display = $storage->load($id);
      $form_display = $alt_display;
    }
  }
}
```